# Node cron, run every midnight

Tags: node.js, cron

I want to run cron job daily at midnight. For this I am using

```
0 0 0 1-31 * *
```

but it doesn't work for me.
I am using the  [node cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron). Please suggest the valid format.

Comment: Using `1-31` for the day field is equivalent to `*`. Other than that, your format is correct. If you edit your question to include more of the relevant code we can help you figure out what's going on here.

Comment: @ev0lution let me check 0 0 0 * * * format.

Comment: All format `00 00 00 * * *`, `0 0 0 * * *` and `0 0 0 1-31` working fine. The problem was in cron's code

Comment: how to run every day at at 9:45 AM

Answer (score 63):

You don't need to set all the fields. Set just first three and it'll take care of running every day at midnight

```
0 0 0 * * *
```

Comment: Why the downvote on this answer? It is 100% correct.

Answer (score 21):

It's quite simple....

The below is the code to run crone job every day 12 AM..

```
var job = new CronJob('0 0 0 * * *', function() {
 //will run every day at 12:00 AM
})
```

For more https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Comment: how to run every day at at 9:45 AM

Comment: It's quite simple. Use this (45 9 * * *) OR (0 45 9 * * *)

Comment: How to run every day at 9:45 AM and PM too. Please reply fast.

Comment: @PeeyushKumar try this (45,45 9,21 * * *). This will work for you.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya Thanks a lot for the help but I got the answer. You have to use 20 in place of 21 because time is count 0-23. 12AM is known as 0.

Comment: @PeeyushKumar lol :D  I am sorry. You are right. It should be (45,45 9,20 * * *)

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya No need to say sorry brother!! :)

Comment: This is another package though

Answer (score 9):

You can try this format too.

```
var CronJob=require('cron').CronJob;
var cronJob1 = new CronJob({

    cronTime: '00 00 00 * * * ',
    onTick: function () {
    //Your code that is to be executed on every midnight
    },
    start: true,
    runOnInit: false
});
```

To understanding something more about cronTime, See the following codes:

cronTime: '00 */3 * * * * ' => Executes in every 3 seconds.

cronTime: '* */1 * * * * ' => MEANING LESS. Executes every one second.

cronTime: '00 */1 * * * * ' => Executes every 1 minute.

cronTime: '00 30 11 * * 0-5 ' => Runs every weekday (Monday to Friday) @ 11.30 AM

cronTime: '00 56 17 * * * ' => Will execute on every 5:56 PM

Answer (score 5):

```
0 0 * * *
```

This pattern will run CronJob job daily at 00:00

https://crontab.guru/examples.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

var job = new CronJob('00 00 00 * * *', function() {
  /*
   * Runs every day
   * at 00:00:00 AM. 
   */
   // DO SOMETHING
  }, function () {
    /* This function is executed when the job stops */
  },
  true /* Start the job right now */
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use crons with **nestjs**/schedule:

```
import { CronExpression } from '@nestjs/schedule';

const EVERY_DAY_AT_MIDNIGHT = CronExpression.EVERY_DAY_AT_MIDNIGHT;

EVERY_DAY_AT_MIDNIGHT === "0 0 * * *"; // true;
```