# How Can I run code hourly using JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I did something like

```
setInterval(function() {
   console.log("!");
   }, 1000 * 60 * 60);
```

I want to run `console.log` every hour but the code doesn't work like what I want.

Let's say that I run the code at 1:30, then It would run `console.log` at 2:30. but What I want to do is run the code every hour. like 1:00, 2:00, 3:00.

Is there any way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: How to do something every full hour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309019/javascript-how-to-do-something-every-full-hour)

Comment: @Xufox Is there any ways to do it using moment.js?

Comment: use node-cron for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499225/i-need-a-nodejs-scheduler-that-allows-for-tasks-at-different-intervals

Comment: @JavaEvgen Thank you so much !!

Comment: @yolohoam I'm happy to hear that I helped you. Thanx

Comment: @JavaEvgen I have only one question for you! I want to run something every 00:00AM, which is turning point of the day, Would this be work? `00 00 0 * * 0-6`

Comment: try this one 0 0 0 * * *. Related to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138163/node-cron-run-every-midnight

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```js
let millisPerHour = 60 * 60 * 1000; // use 5 * 1000 (every 5 seconds) for testing
let millisPastTheHour = Date.now() % millisPerHour;
let millisToTheHour = millisPerHour - millisPastTheHour;

let fn = function() {
  console.log("Running at " + new Date());
}

setTimeout(function() {
  fn();
  
  setInterval(function() {
    fn();
  }, millisPerHour);
}, millisToTheHour);
```

I'm using a combination of `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`. First I calculate the number of milliseconds until the next hour (`millisToTheHour`), then I use a timeout to execute the function and start an interval that will keep executing it every hour.